# How much tax do I have to pay in Redmond, Washington form my Microsoft Research Internship income?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, tax-deduction, international

I am an Indian student studying in Europe. I will be interning at Microsoft Research for 3 months during this summer. I am not sure yet, but most probably I will be visiting US on a J1 visa. Can you please tell me how much tax I have to pay if I get let´s say 5000 USD a month? Also how I have to file taxes and when?

Comment: I interpret https://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/Federal-Income-Tax-Withholding and https://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/Social-Security-Tax---Medicare-Tax-and-Self-Employment as suggesting that your employer in the United States will perform the same tax withholding calculations for you as they would for a U.S. citizen.  If you fill out the W-4 form per the form's instructions, this is likely to result in your withholding being close to (or much higher than) the amount of taxes you will owe.

Comment: If you are not working as an "independent contractor", your employer will probably correctly calculate and withhold the 7.65% employee share of the U.S. Social Security and Medicare taxes.  If you are not working as an "independent contractor", you will not need to worry about filling out any further tax forms regarding this portion of your taxation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An unmarried person with a total U.S.-sourced earned income under $ 37,000 during the year 2016 is likely to owe:

- Somewhat less than 15% of their U.S.-sourced earned income as "federal income taxes", plus:
- 7.65% of their U.S.-sourced earned income as "Social Security taxes" and "Medicare taxes", plus:
- **If they are an independent contractor** another 7.65% of their U.S.-sourced earned income as the "employer share" of their "Social Security taxes" and "Medicare taxes", plus:
- Any state and local income taxes (which do not exist in Washington State), plus:
- **If they are working as a licensed business** any "unemployment insurance premiums" and "workers compensation premiums**.  Each of these can be 0.5% - 4% of pay (below certain caps), depending on the state, business, and industry. Plus
- **If they are working as a licensed business** any state and local "business and occupation taxes" (a.k.a. "B&O taxes").  Washington State has a B&O tax rate slightly below 4% of gross revenue, for many kinds of businesses.

If the original poster is not an "independent contractor", and is not "billing corp-to-corp" then:

- Their employer will pay the B&O taxes, unemployment insurance premiums, workers compensation premiums, and the "employer share" of the "Social Security taxes" and "Medicare taxes".
- The original poster can fill out their "W-4 form" in such a way that their employer will withhold 15% of their pay for federal income taxes.  (One way to do this is to claim 99 dependents, and ask to have "additional withholding" that happens to be 15% of the amount of each pay period's pay.)
- Sometime between January 1, 2017 and April 15, 2017, the original poster can download U.S. federal income tax forms, fill them out, and submit them to the U.S. Internal Revenue Service to claim a refund.

In summary:

- The original poster's net pay is likely to be 22.65% less than their stated pay (if they are working for business that takes care of tax withholding, and are **not** an "independent contractor")
- An "independent contractor" or someone billing "corp-to-corp" (as a business of their own) with a similarly modest income is likely to have a net pay 33% to 40% less than their stated pay.
- These calculations do not consider the effects of other deductions, such as for medical insurance, health savings accounts, dependent care, and retirement savings accounts.
- **These calculations do not consider the effects of taxes by the original poster's home country.**

References:

- https://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/Federal-Income-Tax-Withholding
- https://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/Social-Security-Tax---Medicare-Tax-and-Self-Employment
- https://www.irs.com/articles/projected-us-tax-rates-2016
- https://www.irs.gov/Forms-&-Pubs

Comment: Hi Jasper, Thank you for your help. But I did not understand what is meant by Independent contractor. Will I be categorized as an independent contractor? I have receive the offer directly from microsoft research.

Comment: One more thing is that my total income will be less than 37000 USD as I will be interning for only 3 months. How will that affect the tax calculation?

Comment: Based on your question and your comments, I expect that you are not an "independent contractor".  If you were an "independent contractor", that status would have been made very clear to you, using those exact words.

Comment: At $ 37,651 per year, the marginal tax rate increases from 15% to 25%.  In other words, if you have a taxable income of $ 37,500, you pay $ 5,161 in federal income taxes.  If you make $ 37,600, you pay $5,176.  If you make $ 37,700, you pay $ 5,196.  If you make $ 37,800, you pay $ 5,221.

Comment: Because you are only interning for 3 months, you will make less than $ 37,000.  Thus, you should owe less than 15% of your income in federal income taxes.  My calculations are conservative -- you will probably get a tax refund when you file your taxes.  Pay attention to the W-4 form -- it was not designed for people only working for 3 months, so it might result in more withholding than you need.  As I mention in the answer, you can fill out the W-4 form to say exactly how much withholding you should have per pay period.

Comment: For a closer estimate of how much you might owe in taxes, you can download the 2015 tax forms.  Fill in a guess at your income (such as $ 15,000 = $ 5,000 per month * 3 months), and follow the instructions to estimate your tax bill.  The tax code changes every year, but (for simple taxes like yours) there are only minor differences between the 2015 tax code and the 2016 tax code.

Comment: Thank you very much. Jasper. May I ask your help if I need any more information in the future?